# Paper Napkin Folded

Tags: water, adhesion, osmosis

Why folded napkins are better absorbing water than ordinary napkin. I think there must be related to cohesion of water element. Water are captivated between layers because they appeals each other or some thing like that.  Can some one describe the relations in details.

Edit: since the question is not clear I made some research and find this inspiring video. He explains these issue as "inter tips tissue suspension" or some thing like that. the link is [Joe Smith: How to use a paper towel](http://www.ted.com/talks/joe_smith_how_to_use_a_paper_towel#t-144600)

Comment: Is this true?  I can't find any source that says folded napkins absorb more water.  Seems an easy experiment to do yourself with a kitchen scale.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "folded napkins", and if you think of paper or cloth material napkins. Do you have an example ? (url of image)

Comment: I edited quesiton. @FabriceNEYRET

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two forces involved:

Cohesive forces and adhesive forces. Cohesive forces are forces between alike molecules. That is the reason for drops forming.

Adhesive forces are the forces between unlike molecules. That is the reason why the napkin can suck up the water.

If you fold the napkin, the will be water trapped in the layers. The water molecules are held by the adhesive forces on either side of the water layer and in between water is held by cohesive forces.

If you do not fold the napkin, since the adhesive forces are much stronger, the water gets completely sucked inside the napkin. The only extend water you can hold is a drop (supported by cohesion and gravity).

Comment: waiting for more scientific explanation including some graphics and formulas. If there not I will accept your answer.